# GIT support in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, version-control

I have a project under version control (SVN), and I am using netbenas 7.3.1 as IDE. Fortunately netbeans recognized the version control from the start, and now uses different colors to show modified, new, etc files as following:

[image]

For the second project, I am using Eclipse 3.8 (basically, Eclipse IDE is integrated into the software, and I prefer to stick with that). This project is also under version control (git), but Eclipse does not recognize it. I found out that the version control settings in Eclipse is in Team | share Project, but still can not make it work!

How can I enable version control for my second project in Eclipse in a way that I also get the coloring feature (for modified, new files, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need EGit Team provider and it is included into [Eclipse Kepler Standard package](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-standard-43/keplerr) or you can install it from default eclipse update site from "Collaboration" category. Add git local repository clone into Git Repositories View and use "Import Projects..." from context menu to import projects from working area into workspace. After import projects are gonna be recognized as shared through git.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about 3.8 but previous versions of Eclipse were not bundled with Git support.  You need to install plugins like [EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/) to add Git support to Eclipse.

Everything should be straight-forward after you have that installed :) as you seems to know the right place (Team context menu) to work with version control system.